# HTML5 form input reacting to enter key

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have looked through the available HTML and JS materials in print, and online, concerning the problem of "disabling the enter key" or at least eliminating the default of submitting a form when the enter key is pressed.  My web page needs to ignore form submission until the appropriate button is pushed.  For that matter, I would like to ignore any enter key depression while inside my form. I can send code samples if needed.  I am new to this site and new to web development (Html-CSS-JS-JQ).  I am an old linear programmer so please be merciful on your explanation.  MANY thanks in advance.

Comment: "*… I would like to ignore any enter key depression…*" including inside *textarea* elements?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to do this without JQ

Answer (score 0):

Really simple just do this:

```
$(form).keypress(function (e) {     
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode  == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Source](http://injustfiveminutes.com/2013/02/21/how-to-disable-form-submission-on-enter-key-press-using-jquery/)